# are appimages a way to package AND distribute software or just a way to package?

Tags: appimage

I heard a while back that appimages are *only* a way to package software, not distribute it; however, if I go to the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage):

> AppImage is a format for distributing portable software on Linux without needing superuser permissions to install the application.

So is it both a way of packaging and distributing software, or just packaging?

Answer (score 1):

There's no point whatsoever in a programmer packaging software unless he or she intends to distribute it.

[The AppImage wiki](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki) describes AppImages as "**downloadable files**":

> An AppImage is a downloadable file for Linux that contains an application and everything the application needs to run (e.g., libraries, icons, fonts, translations, etc.) that cannot be reasonably expected to be part of each target system.

Whoever told you AppImages aren't for distribution is probably messing with you.

Comment: so appimages have a package manager, appimages have a way to transport themselves from one computer to another?

Comment: @HowToLinux This is a joke, right?

Comment: @HowToLinux you might be confused about the meaning of the word "distribution".